# Powering a 3 W DC/DC converter

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics

I tried powering a [XP Power IZ2415S](https://www.xppower.com/Portals/0/pdfs/SF_IZ.pdf) and another similar converter with a power supply from an older laptop and it stopped working. I thought it would work because I assumed the laptop supply was voltage regulated and it was the correct level (19 V) for the input to the 3 W supply. Where was I wrong? what would be a appropriate power source for the 3 W converter?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you had the polarity correct? The center is marked positive - is that how you connected it? Also, some of these supplies mark the output voltage with an assumption that it has an appropriate load. Without a load, the output can be much higher - although, I’d guess it would still be within the 36 VDC max of your part.

Comment: If something "stopped working" then under what situation was it previously working? Or maybe you mean the AC/DC power supply stopped working?

Comment: The V+ pin was connected to positive terminal and V- was connected to the negative terminal. I never had a chance to connect anything to it. During initial testing, the correct voltages were on the output pins, but after a few 10s of minutes the converters would not output any voltages (0V). The AC/DC power supply still provides the correct output (19 V).

Comment: Are you doing anything with the remote pin (3)? Pulling it low will disable the output. You should be able to leave it open, but you could try tying it to V+ (pin 2), to be sure.

Comment: I had the same problem with a 3 pin 5 V converter.